# How to remove windows 7 themes

Tags: windows-7, themes

I've installed some themes in Windows 7 from Microsoft site, couple of themes I mistakenly installed twice and I want to remove the duplicated themes. I dont see any uninstall option for themes. I also checked the C:\Windows\Resources\themes folder however the "Bing Dynamic" theme that i want to uninstall is not present there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the themes menu there should be an option when you right click on the theme... `right click -> delete theme`. Note that you can't delete the theme you're currently using, you have to switch to another one first and then delete the theme.

Some themes are located at `%UsersProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` too, as a side note.

Comment: What a perfect example of a UI fail!

Comment: Considering [this Microsoft answers post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-delete-a-theme-in-windows-7/f1d22949-446f-4d7d-a578-fbff4b7b77cb) has 14k views since 2009 and 157 "Me too" points, it seems like we're not the only ones wondering... I wonder why this made it into the final release? Is this the way it is in Windows 8 too? It seems very counter-intuitive to click on another theme before deleting.